# Is there an Out Of The Box way to merge PDF files in a SharePoint O365 Workflow?

Tags: office-365, pdf, merge

I need to Merge attachments (all PDF's) to the end of a PDF generated from list item data. I create a PDF from the list item data and each item has between 2 and 101 attachments. For later use, it is easier to download the one PDF instead of multiple PDF's.

Thanks

Comment: While I can locate Muhimbi to add to a Flow, this is neither free nor an out-of-the-box solution. Is there another way to merge PDF files in SPO?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uNhX6rEqVw) to teach you how to merge the different type of files into one PDF file. I hope I understood your question.

1. Select all files that you want to download
2. Go to **Files**
3. Choose **Convert to PDF**.
4. Check **Merge files**
5. Select the filed to use for bookmarks
6. Specify sort order
7. Insert the **Destination file name**, and **Destination folder**
8. Click the **Convert** button
9. Then you will get your file and go to the folder to download.

Thanks

Comment: I just researched it, actually, this is based on an extension. You can find it in the SharePoint Store. You can add free extension Muhimbi PDF Converter for SharePoint Online to convert and merge your files.

Comment: but for security reason, you should build your own extension.

Comment: Thanks. I will see if I can write my own extension for this. I have started exploring if I can do this using JavaScript (or a variation on JS). I wanted to automate this in a workflow so users only see one file. Less confusion when they begin using this system. Thanks for your help Xin Ning

Comment: Great, by the way, that's add-in in SharePoint store, not extension, I don't know why I wrote extension~~~~Therefore, you can create the add-in, and add it into your workflow.